# How to enable programatically sqlite foreign key support?

Tags: android

In the documentation of sqlite this syntax `PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON;` enables foreign key support. What is the code in Android ?

Answer (score 3):

You can override onOpen in your class that extends SQLiteOpenHelper like this:

```
@Override
public void onOpen(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    super.onOpen(db);
    if (!db.isReadOnly()) {     
        db.execSQL("PRAGMA foreign_keys=ON;");
    }
}
```